# How do i access RecyclerView's row's layout file's?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a switch widget in my RecyclerView's row. I want to access that widget to setOnCheckedChangeListener on the switch So when I use findViewById on the switch within mainActivity it works fine. but when I execute the code the app crashes with this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raunak.alarmdemo4/com.raunak.alarmdemo4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
```

**But why NullPointerException??**

Here's the code snippet
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AlarmRecyclerViewInterface {

    FloatingActionButton mAlarmAddButton;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    AlarmsDBhelperClass mAlarmsDBhelperClass;
    ArrayList<String> nameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList <String> modeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> repeatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hoursArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> minArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Switch mSwitch;
    AlarmAdapter.AlarmView mAlarmView;
    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(hoursArrayList,minArrayList,modeArrayList,repeatArrayList,nameArrayList,this);
    ImageView emptyImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Initializing RecyclerView, DatabaseHelperClass, FAB button, The ON OFF switch & the empty ImageView
        mAlarmsDBhelperClass = new AlarmsDBhelperClass(getApplicationContext());
        mAlarmAddButton = findViewById(R.id.btnAlarmADD);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.alarmList);
        mSwitch = findViewById(R.id.onoff);
        emptyImageView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

        //DividerItemDecoration class is used for getting a vertical line between rows of RecyclerView
        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        //Getting a writable reference of the Database.
        db = mAlarmsDBhelperClass.getWritableDatabase();

        //Retrieving values from the database and storing them in custom ArrayLists
        boolean isDataEmpty = getAlarm(db);

        //Checking if our arrayList is empty? if yes then display some empty list text or an image
        if (!isDataEmpty){
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_alarm_black_white);
            emptyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //FAB Event handling
        mAlarmAddButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.addalarm);
        mAlarmAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddAlarm.class);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(mAlarmView.getAdapterPosition())));
                    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(mAlarmView.getAdapterPosition())));
                    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    startAlarm(c);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alarm Turned ON !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    cancelAlarm();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alarm Turned OFF !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

       //Warping up with the recyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    public boolean getAlarm(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM alarms", new String[]{});
        boolean rowExists;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                nameArrayList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                modeArrayList.add(cursor.getString(3));
                repeatArrayList.add(cursor.getString(4));
                hoursArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(5)));
                minArrayList.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(6)));
                rowExists = true;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }else {
            rowExists = false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return rowExists;
    }

    //RecyclerView's onClick()
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //RecyclerView's onLongClick()
    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(int position) {
        //Updating the recyclerView
        alarmAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        //Deleting the row from the database
        db.delete("alarms","alarm_name=?",new String[]{nameArrayList.get(position)});
        hoursArrayList.remove(position);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm Deleted !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void startAlarm(Calendar c){
        //Getting a System service for the alarm to check the current time with the Alarm set time.
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //Creating an intent to invoke the onReceive method  in the custom receiver class, just to display notifications.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

        //A pending intent is used to execute some work in the future with our applications permissions.
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,0);

        //Now RTC_WAKEUP means if the device is Switched off turn it on.
        //getTimeInMillis() will get get the time in Milliseconds
        //Schedule an alarm to be delivered precisely at the stated time.In my case it's the calendar's getTimeMillis() method. which is providing the correct time in milliseconds.
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,0);

        //Now i'm cancelling the scheduled alarm using AlarmManager's cancel().
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

My Layout:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/onoff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.412" />
```

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class AlarmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmAdapter.AlarmView> {
    //Variables for the main recycler view
    private ArrayList<String> hoursArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> minArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> modeArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> repeatArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> nameArrayList;
    private AlarmRecyclerViewInterface mInterface;

    public AlarmAdapter(ArrayList<String> hours,ArrayList<String> mins,ArrayList<String> mode,ArrayList<String> repeat,ArrayList<String> name,AlarmRecyclerViewInterface mInterface){
        this.hoursArrayList = hours;
        this.minArrayList = mins;
        this.modeArrayList = mode;
        this.nameArrayList = name;
        this.repeatArrayList = repeat;
        this.mInterface = mInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlarmView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_profile,parent,false);
        return new AlarmView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmView holder, int position) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)) < 10 ){
            holder.hours.setText("0"+hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.hours.setText(hoursArrayList.get(position));
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)) < 10){
            holder.mins.setText("0"+minArrayList.get(position));
        }else {
            holder.mins.setText(minArrayList.get(position));
        }
        holder.repeat.setText(repeatArrayList.get(position));
        holder.mode.setText(modeArrayList.get(position));
        holder.name.setText(nameArrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return hoursArrayList.size();
    }

    /*ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            nameArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            modeArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            repeatArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            hoursArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            minArrayList.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };*/

    public class AlarmView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView hours,mins,repeat,name,mode;
        public AlarmView(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hours = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHOUR);
            mins = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMins);
            repeat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRepeatDays);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            mode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMode);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mInterface.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    mInterface.onLongItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Done Adding code

Comment: You can't directly access the `mSwitch` in your Activity. You have to invoke `mSwitch` in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder`. If you need to do anything in your Activity then you can use callback to achieve this

Comment: Use an interface to communicate between adapter and activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access widget's inside RecyclerView's items directly from your Activity. You have to use callback function to achieve this which explain in below:

**Step - 1:** Add this to your Custom Listener Interface:

```
void startCancelAlarm(boolean isStart, int position);
```

**Step - 2:** create a Switch object in your ViewHolder and initialize it in the constructor and add this Listener:

```
mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    mInterface.startCancelAlarm(b,getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

                                                 ^
```

**Step-3** since your `mainActivity` is implementing the Listener you created it will prompt you to implement the method which you added in Step-1, alt + insert and select the method, and write this code under the implementation part remember this is a `callback` function.

```
@Override
    public void startCancelAlarm(boolean isStart, int position) {
        if(isStart){
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hoursArrayList.get(position)));
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minArrayList.get(position)));
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            startAlarm(c);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alarm Turned ON !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            cancelAlarm();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alarm Turned OFF !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

this worked for me.

Comment: but my Adapter's constructor already takes another listener's object which is nothing but, The click listener and the onLongClickListener of the recycler view

Comment: so the this in the adapter's constructor is my custom created interface which is AlarmRecyclerViewIinterface. let me update my code. i forgot to include the class declaration sorry my bad.

Comment: Also you can add the function `startCancelAlarm` in your `AlarmRecyclerViewIinterface` which resolve your problem